# v-model with boolean and array type on same checkbox component

Tags: vue.js

I've got a `BaseCheckbox` component which has been used to bind and trigger single boolean values.

```html
<template>
  <BaseCheckbox v-model="simpleBoolean" ... />
</template>
...
data() { 
  return { simpleBoolean: false }
}
```

Now, I want to bind multiple `BaseCheckbox`es via v-model to an array like its described in the [docs](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/forms.html#checkbox).

```html
<template>
  <BaseCheckbox v-model="fruits" value="apple" />
  <BaseCheckbox v-model="fruits" value="banana" />
</template>
...
data() { 
  return { fruits: [] }
}
```

However, I also want to keep the option to trigger simple boolean values within the same component.  Here is an [example project on stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue-mnde96?file=src/App.vue) where you can reproduce my problem.

I want that fruits array is filled with the value of the checkbox like its done for nuts array. How to achieve this behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may not be the best way to do it but it works.

First of all, `modelValue` is an array, not a boolean. Add this to your BaseCheckbox as an array to make it fill the array:

```
handleInput(id) {
      if (!this.modelValue.includes(id)) {
        this.$emit('update:modelValue', [...this.modelValue, id]);
      } else {
        this.$emit(
          'update:modelValue',
          this.modelValue.filter((value) => value !== id)
        );
      }
    }
```

and then modify your input to remove `checked`:

```
<input :id="id" type="checkbox" v-bind="$attrs" @input="handleInput(id)" />
```

Also, `modelValue` should be an array, not a `boolean`right?

(Not sure whether this [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue-lrzfab?file=src/components/BaseCheckbox.vue) works.)

Comment: Thanks for your help. Your approach is working for arrays but missing boolean type. I fixed your example to work for both, have a look at this [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue-boawfx?file=src/components/BaseCheckbox.vue).